# Create static percentile reference line in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, percentile

[image]I have a scatter plot with a filter that toggles between industry and client specific data. I am able to show the 80th percentile of the industry data as a reference line, but when I filter to the client data the 80th percentile reference line changes to represent the client data.

How can I filter to the client data, but keep the 80th percentile reference line static to the industry data? I basically want the reference line to show the 80th percentile of the industry data when I filter to the client data so I can compare the client data to the industry as a benchmark. Is this possible in Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of Analysis can be easily done with a highlighter instead of filter. I am treating 'Furniture' as your  'Industry' data in below example.

1. Find 80 Percentile of Furniture(Industry) using calculation

> ```
>  IF [Category]='Furniture' THEN 
>      {FIXED [Category]:PERCENTILE([Furniture Profit],0.8)} END
> ```

2. Build the view and add the calcualation '80 Percentile Furniture' to detail
3. Add a reference line as below. Remeber to uncheck 'Show recalculated line for highlighted or selected data points'

   [image]
4. Now you can highlight another category, but the reference line will still show the data for 'Furniture'.
   [image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I think I'm looking for something slightly different. "Category" will be my filter, so when I filter from furniture to technology I want the reference line to stay locked at furniture and the scatter plot to only show the technology data compared to the furniture reference line.